# load more in android listview not working

Tags: android, android-listview

i have tried to do `on scrolling load more` but its not working at all i have used the following code:

Error:

```
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:101)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:63)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:80)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:76)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:101)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:85)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.example.know.FirstActivity.Callpagedetails(FirstActivity.java:176)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.example.know.FirstActivity$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(FirstActivity.java:320)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.example.know.FirstActivity$LoadDataTask.doInBackground(FirstActivity.java:1)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-29 15:55:22.682: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  ... 4 more
```

when i scroll i get the page count is increasing but i didn't get the data could anybody help me regarding this..

i have used the following library [load more in android](https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore)

Comment: put log after Callpagedetails() method and check did you get the data from your webservice

Comment: post more information in your question. We can't find out any solution with this minimum number of code.

Comment: @No_Rulz what kind of information do you need

Comment: Where did you call your handler?

Comment: Put clear information in ur question and add some code

Comment: u can't get the list in listview or problem in scrollview

Comment: @OneManArmy first of all ia m getting the pagecount=0 list item..and on scrolling the same list repeating

Comment: @priya u need mutiple list view im right..

Comment: [ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era ]

Comment: I think till your information is not satisfied check https://bitbucket.org/zedvoid/endlessadapterdemo/src project.. It worked fine for me. if you have any doubts give the comment..

Comment: check http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html also

Comment: @Venkat its all about the code..extra is i have used adapter class to display the data

Comment: @venkat how could i get the data and different method

Comment: @Venkat i am getting the above errors check the edited question

Comment: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" this is because you create a thread inside the asynctask you can't do like this...remove the handler from your code. use ony asynctask

Comment: @Venkat simple asynctask k..it will remove the error but the page is not loading it includes the first pages again and again

Comment: ok remove all the above comments and add your answer here.... congrats @priya2134412

Answer (score 0):

The exception message "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" is very clear.

If you need a Handler instance, then you must create this object in the GUI Thread.
The onCreate() method of your activity is a very good place for this

```
class MyActivity implements Activity {

    ...
    private Handler handler;

    onCreate(...) {
       ....
       handler=new Handler();
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
private void refreshList() {    
Thread threadLoadMore = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {  

       //Here refresh your arraylist 

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {       
           //Here refresh your list view
           yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
      });
    }
  });
  threadLoadMore .start();  
}
```